# Find the value of $3x^4+14x^3+24x^2-6x-10$, when $x=-2+\sqrt{3}i$?

Tags: functions

What will be the value  of $f(x)=3x^4+14x^3+24x^2-6x-10$, when $x=-2+\sqrt{3}i$?
I can evaluate multiplying 4 times. I am looking for a shortcut method?

Comment: Why not just plug this value in the function and calculate the result?

Comment: @roman it's not needed.

Answer (score 4):

TIP: $(x+2)^2 = 3(-1) \implies x^2 + 4x + 7 = 0$. Divide the polynomial from the question by this one and reduce the problem to expand the linear remainder.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ x^2+4x+7 = 0 $ so by division

$$\smash[t]{f(x) =  (3x^2+2x-5)\overbrace{(x^2+4x+7)}^{\large 0} + 25 = 25}$$

**Remark** $ $ If your know modular arithemtic then it is simpler to compute $f(x)\bmod x^2+4x+7,\,$ i.e. use $\,x^2 \equiv -4x-7\,$ to reduce all $x^n,\, n> 2$

This is a generalization of the Remainder Theorem  $\ f(a) = f(x)\bmod (x-a)$

Comment: In $2x^2+2x-5$, it should be $3x^2$.

Comment: @SameerBaheti Typo fixed,  thanks.